# How can I get value stored in session storage (next.js)?

Tags: typescript, next.js, session-storage

I have a slider component where users can set number of columns in my ImageGallery component.

This is my slider component

```
export default function Slider({ value, handleChange }: ISlider) {
  return (
    <input
      className={styles.slider}
      min={1}
      max={3}
      step={1}
      type="range"
      value={value}
      onInput={handleChange}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}

const handleChange = (event: any) => {
  setValue(event.target.value);
};
```

I am trying to store the value from slider in session storage so I can save user preference, and set it using useState function.

```
export default function ImageGallery({
  projects,
}: {
  projects: any;
}): JSX.Element {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(value));
    }
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedValue: string | null = window.sessionStorage.getItem("value");
    const valueData = storedValue ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : 1;
    setValue(valueData);
  }, []);

  const breakpointColumnsObj = {
    default: 4,
    1100: 3,
    700: 2,
    500: value
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Masonry
        breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
        className={styles.myMasonryGrid}
        columnClassName={styles.myMasonryGridColumn}
      >
        {projects.map((item: any) => {
          const images = item.images.data.attributes.formats.large;
          return (
            <ImageCard
              key={item.slug}
              src={images.url}
              alt={item.images.data.attributes.caption}
              width={images.width}
              height={images.height}
              slug={item.slug}
              id={item.slug}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Masonry>
      <Slider value={value} handleChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

then in my home page (static page) i render ImageGallery Component.

Storing data works as intended. The problem I face is that whenever I go back to homepage it sets the value as null regardless of what was stored in session storage (it overrides session storage). Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Somebody form Next.js discord community I have a solution. Changing handleChange function and removing first useEffect (as below) solved the issue.

```
export default function ImageGallery({
  projects,
}: {
  projects: any;
}): JSX.Element {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

      const handleChange = (event: any) => {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
  setValue(event.target.value);
};  

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedValue: string | null = window.sessionStorage.getItem("value");
    const valueData = storedValue ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : 1;
    setValue(valueData);
  }, []);

  const breakpointColumnsObj = {
    default: 4,
    1100: 3,
    700: 2,
    500: value
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Masonry
        breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
        className={styles.myMasonryGrid}
        columnClassName={styles.myMasonryGridColumn}
      >
        {projects.map((item: any) => {
          const images = item.images.data.attributes.formats.large;
          return (
            <ImageCard
              key={item.slug}
              src={images.url}
              alt={item.images.data.attributes.caption}
              width={images.width}
              height={images.height}
              slug={item.slug}
              id={item.slug}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Masonry>
      <Slider value={value} handleChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```